# Modify the DB value before passing to view render (codeigniter)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Fetch database passed into $data['rowVideo'] but I want to change/modify the value from the array? What the best way doing that?

```
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM video";
    $query = $this->db->query($SQL);
    $data['rowVideo'] = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($data['rowVideo'] as $key => $value) {

     // do some  $data['rowVideo'] alteration
     // How would you do it?

    }



   $this->load->view('content', $data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do :

```
$data['rowVideo'][$key] = $modifiedValueCreatedFromValue;
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this as example? $data['rowVideo'][$key]['second'] = secondToMins($data['rowVideo'][$key]['second'])